# JQUERY AJAX - change class of $(this) in case of success

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a div. Inside that div I have multiple elements. Some elements have the class 'myClass'. I also have a button. When clicked, a foreach loop runs for each element that has the class myClass within the div. An ajaxCall is send for each element. The text color of those elements are black by default. In case of success of the ajax call. I would like to remove the class classBlackFont and add the one classGreenFont. I tried the following code which is unfortunately not switching the classes eventhough the ajax call succeeded.

```
$("#someDiv .myClass").each(function() {

    var ajaxData = "myAjaxData";
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "somefile.php",
        data: ajaxData,
        success: function(data) {

            $(this).removeClass('classBlackFont').addClass('classGreenFont');
        }
    });

});​
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`this` is not automatically a reference to the right object in the ajax callback. You can change that by closing over a variable that *does* have the right value:

```
$("#someDiv .myClass").each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var ajaxData = "myAjaxData";
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "somefile.php",
        data: ajaxData,
        success: function(data) {
            $this.removeClass('classBlackFont').addClass('classGreenFont');
        }
    });

});​
```

or by using the [`context` option of `$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

```
$("#someDiv .myClass").each(function() {
    var ajaxData = "myAjaxData";
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "somefile.php",
        data: ajaxData,
        context: this,
        success: function(data) {
            $(this).removeClass('classBlackFont').addClass('classGreenFont');
        }
    });

});​
```

Comment: Thank you very much unwritable name :)

Comment: You're a legend +1

Answer (score 0):

context : this

like something

```
/**
* Default ajax
*/
$.ajaxSetup({
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        context: this
});
```