# Updating form class based on input using database lookup

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, bootstrap-4

I have no clue where to start with this. Basically, I want the class of a input to change to `has-success` when a username that is in a database table called `Username` is equal to the string that the user has written. The current code for the form is:

```
<div class='container col-md-3 rounded p-5 mt-5 border'>
<form action="Authentication.php" method ="post">
    <h3 class='text-center'>Please Login</h3>
    <h5 class='pt-3'>Enter Username and Password</h5>
    <div class="form-group mb-0">
        <input class='form-control float-left mt-3 mb-1' placeholder="Username" type="text" name="username">
        <br>
        <input class='form-control float-left mb-3' placeholder="Password" type="password" name="password">
        <br>
    </div>
    <div class="text-center">
        <input type="submit" class='btn btn-primary btn-sx' value="Login">
    </div>
</form>
</div>
```

So whenever anyone types in the field with `placeholder="username"` it needs to check whether that string matches with any in the column `Username` in the table `Students` and if it does update the class to `success`.

Thanks so much for the help,
Toby

Comment: Use an ajax request to PHP & change the class with pure js or jquery.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JQUERY AJAX - change class of $(this) in case of success](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10298756/jquery-ajax-change-class-of-this-in-case-of-success)

Answer (score 0):

If the code above is in Authentication.php witch is called by the form, then where you check if $_POST has been submitted, initialize a $extraClass = '';
If (your_condition is true) $extraClass = 'success';

and down there in the form, add an

This way it will keep it empty if the condition si not met.